# How do I read a char array from the Serial in setup() and wait long enough for the user to hit send?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am using an Arduino Mega, and it will be bluetooth controlled with a Bluetooth Terminal app for Arduino. What I want it to do is, when it starts up, at setup- I want it to prompt the user for a 4 digit PIN, and once the user is finished entering the pin and hits send the program should proceed further and not before that. This is what I tried

```
unsigned char buff[4];

void getPassword() {

  int j = 0;

  Serial1.println("Enter the PIN: ");

  for (;;) {
    while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
      buff[j] = Serial1.read();
      j++;
    }

    if (j >= 3) {

      break;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {

getPassword();
}
```

It doesn't seem to work at all. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work at all".  Do you mean the Arduino does nothing?  That might mean you didn't upload the code correctly.  Or are there more specific symptoms you could give us?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your password buffer is 4 chars long.  But you are only reading 3 characters from Serial.  IS the password actually 3 or 4 characters long?  If it is 4 characters long, then when j is 3 it isn't time to exit that loop yet.  When j is 3 you are waiting for the fourth character.  You want to exit AFTER you read the fourth character and j gets incremented again and becomes 4.